# Is there a way to enable gmail addons for emails google has deemed unsafe?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

The add-on sidebar simply states "Content not available for this message" if Google thinks the email is unsafe.

There does not seem to be any manifest options that help with this, or at least I could not find any mentions out there.

Is there a way to enable gmail addons for emails google has deemed unsafe?

Comment: Is this the one you are referring to? [Build Gmail Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/building).

Comment: Yes, I built up a simple add-on with Gmail Add-ons to show some information about emails, and noticed that add-ons do not run at all for some suspicious emails. Which i'd like.

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Comment: i have the same issue but i didnt even know that this "Content not available for this message" line means that the email is unsafe. Whatever that means. I have some of these emails as well and they are definitely not unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. This issue is pending with Google. The problem occurs when the incoming email contains an SPF failure message. It seems that any SPF failure, even a soft-fail, causes the add-on to ignore the email, even if the email is otherwise 100% safe. There's apparently no quick fix. As a clunky workaround, you can manually forward the incoming email (eg to a dummy address), and this will allow the add-on to process the thread.

Google apparently considers this to be intentional behaviour, and they aren't planning to fix it (although they plan to add more detail to the error message).

More info here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112064778